# embedded iframe on full browser window

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, iframe

I am stuck in weird situation. 
I have a JSP+Servlet+Spring MVC application embedded via `iframe` in a parent application which is developed in Angular4.

Now for session idle timeout, Spring MVC app redirects to a logout page ( through Java code ) so logout page is displayed within `iframe` while rest of parent window remains as is.

Logout page is an external URL.

Will it be possible to display that logout page when redirection happens from Spring MVC app for whole browser window so parent content also disappear ?

I am not sure if that is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

May this work for you
try this code after some **event** happens

```
parent.window.history.pushState({}, 'Title', '/contextPath/controller/logout');
parent.location.reload();
```

[Read Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

You use above code in javascript/jQuery, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896637/3425489) will help you for **EVENT**